# sql accumulating decimals at the end

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need help with a simple query for dividing a value to equal numbers. But I also want to avoid decimals values to accumulate them all to the final value.This is achievable by query below, however if I choose different datatype such as **MONEY** or **NUMERIC** for **@amt**, it gets tricky. Can anyone do what I did below with **MONEY** or **NUMERIC** datatype?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id TINYINT, princ NUMERIC (14,2))
DECLARE @counter INT  = 1
DECLARE @term TINYINT = 12
DECLARE @amt INT = 50000
DECLARE @decimals INT = @amt-((@amt/@term)*@term)

WHILE @counter <= @term

    BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @tbl (id,princ)
            SELECT  @counter, @amt/@term
            SET @counter = @counter + 1
            UPDATE @tbl SET princ = princ+@decimals WHERE id = @term
    END

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Comment: As a side note `DECLARE @decimals INT = @amt-((@amt/@term)*@term);` is a tidier syntax.

Comment: thank you :) I just updated the code

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Do what you need to do you populate the table, excluding the last row>

INSERT INTO
  @tbl (
    id,
    princ
  )
SELECT
  MAX(id) + 1,
  @amt - SUM(princ)
FROM
  @tbl
```

Or, perhaps, with a CTE...

```
WITH
  recursive_distribution AS
(
  SELECT 0 AS id, CAST(@amt / @term AS INT) AS princ

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id + 1, princ
    FROM recursive_distribution
   WHERE id < @term - 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 1, @amt - (princ * (@term-1))
    FROM recursive_distribution
   WHERE id = @term - 1
)
INSERT INTO
  @tbl (id, princ)
SELECT
  id, princ
FROM
  recursive_distribution
WHERE
  id > 0
OPTION
  (MAXRECURSION 0)  -- Only needed if @term >= 100
```

*(Starting at 0, then excluding row 0 means this can cope with @term = 1)*

Comment: But that's goal, to accumulate all rounding at the end. I want to avoid values with decimal.

Comment: Then use the first one...  Populate the first @term-1 rows *(all except the last row)*, then use the insert statement given...